# Laravel Asset Links not working

Tags: html, laravel

I want to install the "Metronic" Admin Theme in Laravel and therefore adjust the links in the header to the correct paths.

The current header looks like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Metronic Admin Theme #1 | Blank Page Layout</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <meta content="Preview page of Metronic Admin Theme #1 for blank page layout" name="description" />
    <meta content="" name="author" />
    <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700&subset=all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../assets/global/plugins/simple-line-icons/simple-line-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL STYLES -->
    <link href="../assets/global/css/components.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="style_components" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../assets/global/css/plugins.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END THEME GLOBAL STYLES -->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME LAYOUT STYLES -->
    <link href="../assets/layouts/layout/css/layout.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../assets/layouts/layout/css/themes/darkblue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="style_color" />
    <link href="../assets/layouts/layout/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- END THEME LAYOUT STYLES -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" /> </head>
<!-- END HEAD -->
```

I copied all the folders needed into the `resources/assets/` folder, but still it is not found when loading the page and no matter how I change the path it is not found. How would I need to adjust this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can use {{asset}} which  allows you to link to an asset within
>   your public directory

try

```
<link href="{{ asset('/global/css/components.min.css') }}"" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset

Comment: When I adjust this for the script tags: `<script src="{{asset('assets/global/plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>` I get the error `syntax error, unexpected 'assets' (T_STRING)`

Answer (score 1):

Copy `assets` folder of **Metronic** theme and past to your application's `public` folder. Add your resource link by following line:

```
 <link href="/assets/global/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

By Metronic you maybe forgot to call

```
npm run dev
```

or

```
npm run prod
```

according to docs
[Metronic Laravel](https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs&section=laravel-quick-start)